# how to calculate substraction from 2 values in a table with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table

I want to calculate the substraction from the volume for each day towards the day before.

How can I do that with jquery?

```js
//I tried to use `map` function but don't know how to handle this

const volumes = $('tr td.volume').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(volumes)
// now i have all the volume values; bu how to abstract for each and inject val in `consumed` class?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">660</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (680 - 660)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">680</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 30 (710 - 680)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">710</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (730 - 710)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">730</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 50 (780 - 730)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-11</td>
    <td class="volume">780</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Remember that SO is here to help you debug code you've written, not to write code for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the `680` comes from the second row

Comment: I made you a working snippet. Your selector was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each element with the `volume` class, get the element with the `volume` class in the next row, get the difference, and assign that to the innerHTML of the sibling with the `consumed` class.

```js
$('.volume').each(function() {
  const next = $(this).parent().next().find('.volume')
  $(this).siblings('.consumed').html(+next.html() - $(this).html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">660</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">680</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">710</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">730</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-11</td>
    <td class="volume">780</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS version

```js
const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody tr")];
trs.forEach((row, i) => {
  if (i < trs.length - 1) {
    const vol1 = row.querySelector(".volume").textContent;
    const vol2 = trs[i + 1].querySelector(".volume").textContent;
    row.querySelector(".consumed").textContent = vol2 - vol1;
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
      <td class="volume">660</td>
      <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (680 - 660)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
      <td class="volume">680</td>
      <td class="consumed">text should be 30 (710 - 680)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
      <td class="volume">710</td>
      <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (730 - 710)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
      <td class="volume">730</td>
      <td class="consumed">text should be 50 (780 - 730)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">2021-08-11</td>
      <td class="volume">780</td>
      <td class="consumed"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized after writing this that each column had it's own class assigned, so this could probably be written a little neater as my solution relies on your exact table structure.

```js
// Get rows
var $tr = $('tr');

// loop through rows except last
for (var i = 0; i < $tr.length - 1; i++) {
  // current row and next row under it
  var row = $tr.get(i);
  var next_row = $tr.get(i + 1);

  // Grab values from volumn column
  var v1 = parseInt($(row).children('td')[1].innerHTML);
  var v2 = parseInt($(next_row).children('td')[1].innerHTML);

  // Calc new value
  var new_val = v2 - v1;

  // Put new value in 3rd column
  $(row).children('td')[2].innerHTML = new_val;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">660</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (680 - 660)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">680</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 30 (710 - 680)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">710</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 20 (730 - 710)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">730</td>
    <td class="consumed">text should be 50 (780 - 730)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-11</td>
    <td class="volume">780</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The element would have to be turned into a jquery object first before one could use html() function. It's unnecessary overhead for something as simple as retrieving a value. I understand the function has a few safety checks included but in this instance there's really no point.

Comment: But there is SO MUCH CODE in your example. No need to parseInt if you subtract for example and `$('.consumed',row).html(new_val)` is easier to understand and read than `$(row).children('td')[2].innerHTML = new_val` to take just one of the statements

Comment: You are taking a jQuery object and turning it into a DOM object before you use it, and then into a jQuery object again to take the DOM child -  That is weirder

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Phaelax's solution to allow for your table structure changing but maintaining those classes (would add as a comment, but I don't have enough rep points for that yet):

```
// Get rows
var tr = $('tr');

// loop through rows except last
for(var i=0; i < tr.length - 1; i++){
  // current row and next row under it
  var row      = tr[i];
  var next_row = tr[i+1];
  
  // Grab values from volume column
  var v1 = parseInt($(row).children('td.volume').text());
  var v2 = parseInt($(next_row).children('td.volume').text());
  
  // Calc new value
  var new_val = v2 - v1;
  
  // Put new value in 3rd column
  $(row).children('td.consumed').text(new_val);
  
}
```

You might even be able to refine it a bit more from here by putting a similar loop in a:

```
$('tr').each(function(row) {
});
```